# Iterate throught map that has following structure

Tags: java, dictionary, key-value

So, the matter is that I've the following object `Map<String, List<String>>`
Some function have returned info inside this structure, so the output, when I execute this snippet

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) 
{
System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " ,Value : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Corresponding output looks like

```
Key: Somekey1
Value: Somevalue1
Key: Somekey2
Vaue: Somevalue2, Somevalue3
Key: foobar
Value: foo, foo1, ..., foon
```

So, as you can see, there is no way to get around all the elements needed, because I only need every value with `foobar` key to be represented as `String[]`, for instance.

The ultimate thing is that, according to javadoc, finally I will get `foon` if the value of `foobar` key is needed.

```
String fookey = conn.getHeaderField("foobar");

    if (fookey == null) {
        System.out.println("Key 'foobar' is not found!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("foobar: " + fooval);
    }
```

This code in my output has `foo1`

Can somebody come out with the working snippet of code, or the idea how to solve this issue?

UPD.

Now the the solution found. Feel free to improve it if you know how.
Tried to maintain code copy-pastable for others.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String strArray = {""};
for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry: map.entrySet()){
if(map.containsKey("foobar")){
List list = entry.getValue();
strArray = (String[])list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
}
} 
for(String str : strArray){sb.append(str + newline);}
String fooarr = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

`entry.getValue()` returns you a `List<String>`

if you want them as `String[]` you can do something like this :

```
List list = entry.getValue();

String[] strArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Comment: Sorry, can not vote up. Thanks for advice, but yor solution "as is" didn't solve issue. See my update to know the solution.

Comment: No problem, yeah basically `list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);` is what you were looking for. Glad to hlep.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow but if you just want the values with key `foobar`

```
if(map.containsKey("foobar"))
{
    String[] theValsAsArray = map.get("foobar").toArray()
}
```

Comment: Sorry, can not vote up. Thanks for advice, but yor solution "as is" didn't solve issue. See my update to know the solution.